# Geometry Nodes Collisons

Tags: node-editor, physics, collision, geometry-nodes

I have a model that's made up of geometry nodes. They're intersecting. I want them to collide. What do I need to add to the node tree to make them collide?

I tried following this, but I don't see a distance parameter anywhere.
[Reddit Geometry Collision Question](http://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/ma7qxq/geometry_node_point_instancing_and_collision/)

My blend file: [Geometry Person](https://pasteall.org/blend/7ae3cdd74bcb45949426addda03e467b)

[image: Mesh]

[image: Node Tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is change the distance parameter in the "Point distribute"-node until they don't collide anymore.

[image]

Comment: That's much better. Thank you! Is there a way to make the large and small spheres not intersect with each other now?